# How do I avoid loading all child records with the actual table

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I have a web API developed on .net framework. I need to load records of a single table "jobs" to populate a listview in my mobile app. When I do this with below code I get all other child records associated with the "Jobs" table, which I don't need as they are taking time to load and making my app load slow.

```
 [HttpGet]
        public async Task<List<Job>> Jobs()
        {
            //   return await db.Jobs.SqlQuery("select id,account,category,Title,Description,Price,Type,PreferredDate,PreferredTime,Hours,Days,Latitude,Longitude,Video,CreatedDate,UpdatedDate,Sort,Status from jobs where status='Posted' order by Updateddate desc").ToListAsync();
            return await db.Jobs.Where(x => x.Status == "Posted").OrderByDescending(x=>x.UpdatedDate).ToListAsync();
        }
```

http://zameeli.com/jobs/jobs

this is the where you can see the web API output which will load all child tables. I just need to load a single table or at least exclude a particular table ("Bids" Table)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can disable lazy loading, in your Jobs model remove virtual from children that you don't want to load.if you want to disable it permanently you must disable it globally more info [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/64014#issuecomment-443622648)